# In Robolectric test, how to wait for messages in the main looper to be run?

Tags: android, robolectric

I'm testing a Service using Robolectric 3. Once run, it registers an anonymous BroadcastReceive waits for the system to send a broadcast after some event occurred.

In the test I initialize the service so that it registers the BroadcastReceiver, then I trigger the system event, then I verify that the service state changed accordingly after the broadcast is handled. But because the `onReceive` method is run asynchronously, the assertions are run too soon.

But using `Thread.sleep` in the test didn't work (and it's code smell I guess), `onReceive` is not called anyway.

Doing step-by-step debugging into Robolectric code I see the BroadcastReceiver is correctly registered and the broadcast is sent to the main looper's scheduler, but then nothing happens.

So how can I make the main scheduler run the pending actions and let my test wait for their completion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Robolectric, the scheduler of a Service is normally in paused state. Any message that is put into the queue is not run until the time is not "advanced" by certain amount.

Given a Service `myService`, you can access its Robolectric scheduler and run its enqueued messages:

```
org.robolectric.util.Scheduler scheduler = shadowOf(myService.get().getMainLooper()).getScheduler();
while (!scheduler.advanceToLastPostedRunnable()) ;

// ... put your test assertions here
```

Please note that the shortcut `Robolectric.flushForegroundThreadScheduler()` only runs all the messages that were in the queue at that time; if any of those put other messages, they won't be executed.